# How to pass the parent_id in the nested resource to get, in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I have the following in routes.rb

```
resources :users, only: [:index, :update, :destroy] do
    resources :expenses, except: :show
end
```

And it generates the following route, among others :

```
user_expenses GET    /users/:user_id/expenses(.:format)            expenses#index
```

I am using devise for authentication and I want to check after sign in if I get to the expenses_index page. My test:

```
it "should let a user see all the expenses" do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  login_with ( @user )
  get user_expenses_path,  { :user_id => @user.id }
  expect( response ).to render_template( :index )
end
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"expenses"} missing required keys: [:user_id]
```

I added a byebug before the get and verified that @user.id indeed has the user_id required.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try: `get user_expenses_path( :user_id => @user.id )` instead... `user_expenses_path` is a method and it expect you to pass a user-id to that method... the way you have it now, you are passing user id as the second parameter to the method `get` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
get user_expenses_path,  { :user_id => @user.id }
```

try:

```
get user_expenses_path( :user_id => @user.id )
```

`user_expenses_path` is a method that expects you to pass a user-id as a parameter in order to build the required path

The way you have it now, you are passing user id as the second parameter to the `get` method instead - it doesn't need it and just throws it away